# Separating duplicates of a selected mesh by the cursor in Meshlab

Tags: point-clouds, meshlab

I have 1 .ply file with a point cloud coordinates (in ASCII) and I would like to create multiple copies of this last one in the same project using Meshlab and then export it again.

I am neither intending to align the PC (e.g with ICP) nor do anything else with the point cloud, I simply want to create copies of the point cloud, separate the copies with my mouse and then export the result as .ply again.

What I tried:

- Opening the file multiple times: didn't work, very understandable.
- creating a copy of the file and import it.
- creating duplicates of the same point cloud: it shows on the right list in Meshlab, that the duplicates are created, I couldn't figure out how to separate these (only using the mouse).

I would really like to know if there is a way to do so in Meshlab using the mouse or any suggestions, please note that I am not interested in anything like translation matrices...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not completely clear what you mean with *separate*.
If you mean *translate* the duplicated mesh, then you just have to

- load the point cloud
- Filter "*Duplicate Current Layer*"
- Translate it, you can do it in two ways, either using the filter "*Transform: Translate*" or using the manipulator tool (this icon in the toolbar)

[image]

Comment: It is what I was looking for (manipulator tool), I also use the "Flatten Visible Layers" tool to merge the duplicates into 1 point cloud and then export it as ply.
I will mark your answer as accepted, it is answering what I asked.